# unable to recognize the Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, emf

I encountered an annoying problem such that my Eclipse (Juno) failed to recognize the Java project that I generated by using Eclipse Modeling Framework.

So the detail is that I first generated a Java project by using EMF from my class diagram. Then I made some changes (only filled in some implementation functions inside the class, didn't touch any of the auto-generated skeleton) and sent it to my friend. But his eclipse seemed not be able to recognize this project and it is simply not run-able (The ´J´ icon became 'shallow' instead of solid). He imported the project into an empty EMF project. Then we tried any other EMF project it was still the same.

Then we tried to create a Java empty project and import it there. It still could't work because the Java project we tried to import was generated from EMF so it seemed that it cannot be directly used in another Java empty project.

So I am wondering is there any 'neat' way to solve this problem? Thanks very much!

Comment: Did you include the `.project` file? Eclipse won't recognize a project without this. On Linux and Mac OS X this is a hidden file so you might have missed it. There are other hidden files such as .classpath as well.

Comment: @greg-449 oh it might be this issue. But I am still a little bit concerned. Since the generated project is a Java project, but it was from a EMF project. Not sure if it will work after I include the .project file..